# How to create one directory in the tree of directories ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, files, directory, home-directory, desktop-directories

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` a little while ago and I consider myself a beginner.

I get the following window:

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to create a folder in the "Places" area in the tree of directories Ubuntu?

And I was wondering also you can create another region beyond the three standard areas "Places", "Device" and "Network"? Is there something similar in Gnome like the structure of the Windows directory tree?

This would help me a lot to organize my directories, for I have now created many folders in my folder pesssoal in `/home/ricardoramos/` and I am polluted my folder `Desktop` with new files and folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create Bookmarks. Just go inside the folder you want to bookmark and select **Bookmark this location** in the Bookmarks section of the top panel. Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Hello @incBrain, if I want to undo the process Bookmarks, as I do?

Comment: @ricardoramos press Ctrl+B and you will see all the bookmarks. You can then rearrange them and delete them. You also can just simple right click on it and remove

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @incBrain, was exactly what I needed! I would like to congratulate you for their knowledge of Ubuntu!

Comment: @ricardoramos you are welcome :)